# Consulta sqlsrv_query con fechas

Tags: sql

Quiero obtener todas las filas donde el campo subido sea null o 0 que eso lo hace bie, pero al comparar las fechas no me lo hace y me coge todas y no el rango que le he puesto

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos_ventas WHERE subido is null or subido = 0 AND fecha >= '".$inicio."' AND fecha <= '".$fin."'";
```

Comment: Prueba de la siguiente manera: $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos_ventas WHERE subido is null or subido = 0 AND (fecha >= "'.$inicio.'" AND fecha <= "'.$fin.'")";

Comment: El fallo era l oque me comentastes de utilizar el parentesis pero tambien lo tuve que poner en la otra condición  $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos_ventas WHERE (subido is null or subido = 0) AND (fecha >= "'.$inicio.'" AND fecha <= "'.$fin.'")";

Comment: Si, disculpa, me comi ese parentesis. Lo voy a colocar como respuesta a la pregunta para que quede cerrada. Puedes por favor marcarla como la respuesta correcta? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui debajo dejo el pedazo de codigo que le funciono y logramos hacerlo junto con @daniellandete. Era solo cuestion de parentesis en las condiciones y cambiar el orden de las comillas dobles y simples. Las dobles por fuera y las simples por dentro.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos_ventas WHERE (subido is null or subido = 0) AND (fecha >= "'.$inicio.'" AND fecha <= "'.$fin.'")";
```